# .net core arquivos json

Tags: c#, json, visual-studio, mvc, asp-net-core

Estou fazendo uma aplicação web simples, ela vai ler um arquivo json:

```
{
    "hotelName" : "Jumeirah Creekside Hotel",
    "thumb": "https://loremflickr.com/130/100/dubai",
    "stars" : 5,
    "location" : "Garghoud",
    "city": {
        "id": "132",
        "name": "Dubai"
    },
    "country": "UAE",
    "date": "2019-03-17",
    "price": 800,
    "class": "First Class",
    "guest": 1
  },
```

E preciso usar os dados desse arquivo em uma página web. Já criei as classes do Json. Estou usando o asp net core mvc, e não sei onde chamar o metodo de leitura do mesmo arquivo. 
Estou usando File para ler o arquivo, e quero usar Newtonsoft para converter, acho que meu erro está mesmo na estrutura do mvc.

```
    namespace MyTrips
{
    public class Host
    {
        public string hotelName { get; set; }
        public string thumb { get; set; }
        public int stars { get; set; }
        public string location { get; set; }
        public City city { get; set; }
        public string country { get; set; }
        public string date { get; set; }
        public int price { get; set; }
        public string @class { get; set; }
        public int guest { get; set; }
    }
}

namespace MyTrips
{
    public class City
    {
        public object id { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: E aquela `,` no final do Json? você está recebendo apenas um objeto ou uma coleção?

Comment: Inclua o código de onde você está tentando ler o arquivo

Answer (score 0):

O mapeamento segundo o JSON postado está correto com uma ressalva que tem uma  `@class` retira esse @ e outra coisa é o "***,***" no final do arquivo. Outra coisa você tem certeza que tipo `Price` deveria ser realmente `int`? Faz sentido ser um Double.